# SharedPreferences integer addition

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a code... Its excellent save data and load data, but... When i reset application, my score loading, but when i click button for +5 score, my score reset and set 5. I am want that addition +5, but its dont work...

I understand that the problem of addition, because save and load working excellent, but addition doesnt work.

Sorry for my bad English :)

```
int mCounts;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    setContentView(R.layout.appli);
    Settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int mCounts = Settings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SCORE, 1);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

    score.setText(String.valueOf(mCounts));


}
public void five(View view) {
    score.setText(String.valueOf(mCounts += 5)+"");
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();



    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Settings.edit();
    editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SCORE, mCounts);
    editor.apply();


}
```

Comment: where is button code?

Comment: public void five(View view) {
    score.setText(String.valueOf(mCounts += 5)+"");
}

Comment: First off, why are you doing `mCounts += 5` inside the `String.valueOf()` call, instead of on the line before it? I know it's supposed to work, but it's very unclear, since it looks like you're just outputting a value, and you're obscuring the fact that the value is intended to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your button:

```
    public void five(View view) {
        score.setText(String.valueOf(mCounts += 5)+"");

     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Settings.edit();
        editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SCORE, mCounts);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Problem is here:

```
int mCounts = Settings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SCORE, 1);
```

Remove `int`. it will work

Comment: @Kylmen finally i got the problem. see the updated answer :)